# How do I make NSTextView's findBar return focus to the editing area?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I have an `NSTextView` with `usesFindBar = YES` and `incrementalSearchingEnabled = YES`. If I press ⌘F to summon the find bar, then press escape to hide the find bar, the focus is not returned to the text area, even though `self.window.firstResponder` is still the text view (I printed it out with a timer). Pressing tab returns focus to the editor, though. How can I do that automatically?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @sam sorry, I haven't tried the top answer, but it seemed reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting this weird behavior too where dismissing the find bar results in seemingly no first responder. Pressing 'tab' returns the enclosed text view to first responder status just as in the original question.

My horrible hack is to subclass the enclosing `NSScrollView` and take advantage of the fact that it conforms to the `NSTextFinderBarContainer` protocol. I override `-setFindBarVisible:`.

```
@implementation HorribleHackScrollView

- (void)setFindBarVisible:(BOOL)findBarVisible {
    [super setFindBarVisible:findBarVisible];
    if (self.findBarView && self.isFindBarVisible == NO) {
        [self.window makeFirstResponder:self.documentView];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Nice solution, Sam!

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I've solved this.
My task was a little different, but I guess this will be pretty useful to you and others.

**Here is how you can detect the event of the findBar show/hide.**

1) Subclass the `NSScrollView` and override the `-(void)tile` method.

Note: *_findBarIsVisible* is the iVar initially set to NO.

```
- (void)tile
{
    [super tile];

    // check if findBar did showUp or disappeared
    CGFloat fullHeight = self.bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat clipHeight = self.contentView.bounds.size.height;

    if (!_findBarIsVisible && fullHeight > clipHeight)
    {
        _findBarIsVisible = YES;
        NSLog(@"findBarIsVisible: %d", _findBarIsVisible);
    }
    else if (_findBarIsVisible && fullHeight == clipHeight)
    {
        _findBarIsVisible = NO;
        NSLog(@"findBarIsVisible: %d", _findBarIsVisible);
    }
}
```

Now you have your event of toggling the findBar. Just put some required code here or notify some controller about the event (like I did).

In your case, I guess you should do something like:

```
[self.window makeFirstResponder:self.documentView];
```

in the section where the findBar hides.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem in iOS development. It seemed that the `firstResponder` flag was not correctly "taken" from the former UI element I had in use. I solved it by resigning the `firstResponder` from my `UITextfield` programmatically when focusing on the `UISearchBar` and then assigned it manually too. This worked perfectly. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, though I don't think this helps. :\ I can't tell when the user summons the bar, or when they dismiss the bar, and the first responder for the window is always the text view even when the bar is up.